# Unable to change the value of a property of an Object - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have a module in my code and I'm unable to change the value of a property of an Object. I have a more detailed explanation in code, see below:

```
var network = (function(){ // Created a closure.
  var ajax = { 
    response: 0, // I set the initial value of response to 0
    parse: function(x){
             var y = JSON.parse(x);
             ajax.response = y; // This is where things don't seem to work. Value of response is still 0.
           }
    // Some other code.

    } // End of ajax object.

    return { // I return an Object .
     invoke: function(x){ ajax.parse(x); },
     reply: ajax.response
     }

})();

network.invoke(valid_argument); // I invoke the function and pass a valid json string received from a server via ajax.
console.log(network.reply); // I get 0, which is the initial value. Why?
```

As mentioned in the Code this issue feels weird, any help is appreciated.

Comment: there is no _response_  available in the function. It is inside the ajax object

Comment: The "a" in ajax stands for *asynchronous* ?

Comment: @brk Oops! That was supposed to be reply, I corrected it now. Can you please take a look now?

Comment: @adeneo yea..but why is that required, now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get 0, which is the initial value. Why?

Because `reply: ajax.response` assigns to `reply` (a copy of) the value that `ajax.response` has *at the moment the line is executed*. Future changes to `ajax.response` don't affect `reply`, there is no intrinsic connection between these two properties.

Here is a simplified example of the same situation:

```
var x = 42;
var y = x;
x = 21;
console.log(y); // still 42
```

JavaScript is [*pass-by-value*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value), not [*pass-by-reference*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference). That means that a copy of the value is assigned to `reply`, not a reference to the `ajax.response` property.

Comment: Would it help if i use a function to return the value of ajax.response because it's during runtime . Like this :  reply: function(){ return ajax.response;}

Comment: If you mean `reply: function() { return ajax.response; }`, then yes because then `ajax.response` is evaluated every time `reply` is called, not only once when the object is constructed.

Answer (score 0):

@Teja: Felix King has show you the technical aspect and it's true. I want to give my 2 cents about code quality.
Javascript allow we to code in a very flexible way, and it really look confusing, Javascript code is very hard to read. So does you code snippet, look over complicated. Avoid too much use of function.

@Felix King: I think pass by value or pass by reference is not relevant here. These concepts are applied for the case the parameters passed to a function, not in an assignment operation.